# Vampire B-movie from mid 1990s to early 2000s involving a tiger and pie

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, vampire

I remember very little about this movie, but I saw it a long time ago so I know it is at least older than me. The main character is some random nerd guy who gets picked on by some other blonde guy in a Hawaiian shirt, I THINK. The main character was at a diner when he someone threw a pie in his face and laughed at by everyone. He later becomes the hero of the movie when a vampire creature starts terrorizing his town.

The end of the movie takes place in a mansion where a tiger or maybe a werewolf 
is loose in the hallways. The tiger gets impaled by a spear and transforms into the blonde guy from earlier in the movie. Finally the main villain who is apparently a vampire turns into a giant ugly bat creature, but the main character man tears off the curtains of a giant window and the vampire explodes. This was a strange movie and it was pretty corny.

Comment: I am 100 percent certain it was the movie Fright Night. I have no idea were I got the Hawaiian shirt from but the scene with the tiger was actually a wolf and the pie was a sandwich. I knew the name Brewster sounded familiar, for 12 years I thought it was just a dream. Now I will watch the movie. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I've added a Community Wiki answer. You can accept that answer, or post your own and accept it, by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Noting that the original querent [identified the film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/199276/vampire-b-movie-from-mid-1990s-to-early-2000s-involving-a-tiger-and-pie?rq=1#comment546566_199276) as *Fright Night*.

> I am 100 percent certain it was the movie Fright Night. I have no idea were I got the Hawaiian shirt from but the scene with the tiger was actually a wolf and the pie was a sandwich. I knew the name Brewster sounded familiar, for 12 years I thought it was just a dream. Now I will watch the movie. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I've found no mention of a Hawaiian shirt, or a pie, but the 1972 Hammer Films release, [*Vampire Circus*](https://www.popmatters.com/137218-vampire-circus-2496076461.amp.html) has a vampire turning into a panther and has a tiger in another segment.

Answer (score 0):

The ending reminds me of Hammer Films' *[Dracula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracula_(1958_film))* (from 1958) or the film *[Fright Night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fright_Night)* (from 1985).  In *Fright Night* there is also a character who turns into an animal, in this case a wolf, indoors and attacks someone.

So it seems possible that you might remember either of these films.

Comment: Vampires turning into things (animals) and exploding seem pretty common tropes. Do any of these films match the more unusual elements (Hawaiian shirt, pie-in-the-face, tiger, etc)?

Comment: I've converted your links into [inline links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) as this is more reader-friendly.